# If any potential issues using xpath find/update xml tag text

Tags: python, xml, xpath, elementtree, xml-namespaces

I wrote a script, based on some of the existing StackOverflow questions, but no one perfectly fit my issues.
The user use xpath to find a XML tag from a given XML file, and update the tag text based on user inputs.
Below is my script using **Python 3** (The most difficult part for me is around the namespaces):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import sys

# user inputs and variables
filename = 'actors.xml'
xpath = 'actor/name'
value = 'test name'
temp_namespace = 'temp_namespace'
    
# get all namespaces    
all_namespaces = dict([node for _, node in ET.iterparse(filename, events=['start-ns'])])

# register namespace
for key in all_namespaces.keys():
    ET.register_namespace(key, all_namespaces[key])

# remove all namespace from elements first
# and temp save it to tag attribute
# The below logic is copied from other Stackoverflow answers
# From **Python 3.8**, we can add the parser to insert comments
it = ET.iterparse(filename, parser=ET.XMLParser(target=ET.TreeBuilder(insert_comments=True)))
for _, el in it:
    prefix, has_namespace, postfix = el.tag.partition('}')
    if has_namespace:
        el.tag = postfix
        el.set(temp_namespace, prefix + has_namespace)

# find and update
root = it.root
for el in root.findall(xpath):
    el.text = str(value)

# get xml comments before root level
doc_comments = []
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith('<?xml'):
            continue
        if line.startswith('<' + root.tag):
            break
        else:
            doc_comments.append(line)

def add_tag_namespace(el):
    for sub_el in el:
        if temp_namespace in sub_el.attrib.keys():
            sub_el.tag = sub_el.attrib[temp_namespace] + sub_el.tag
            del sub_el.attrib[temp_namespace]
        add_tag_namespace(sub_el)
    if temp_namespace in el.attrib.keys():
        el.tag = el.attrib[temp_namespace] + el.tag
        del el.attrib[temp_namespace]

# add all namespace back 
# and delete the temp namespace attribute         
add_tag_namespace(root)

# write back to xml file        
tree = ET.ElementTree(root) 
tree.write(filename, encoding='unicode', xml_declaration=True)

if len(doc_comments) == 0:
    sys.exit()

# write xml comments before root back
lines = []
# first read all lines
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
# second, insert xml comments back into memory
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if line.startswith('<?xml'):            
        insert_at = i + 1
        for comment in doc_comments:
            lines.insert(insert_at, comment)
            insert_at += 1
        break
# finally, write all contents to file
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    for line in lines:
        f.write(line)
```

actors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<actors xmlns:fictional="http://characters.example.com"
        xmlns="http://people.example.com">
    <actor>
        <name>John Cleese</name>
        <fictional:character>Lancelot</fictional:character>
        <fictional:character>Archie Leach</fictional:character>
    </actor>
    <actor>
        <name>Eric Idle</name>
        <fictional:character>Sir Robin</fictional:character>
        <fictional:character>Gunther</fictional:character>
        <fictional:character>Commander Clement</fictional:character>
    </actor>
</actors>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have removed the logic of using lxml, and found a new way to get all namespaces

Comment: "The most difficult part for me is around the namespaces" - Please clarify exactly what the  problem is and how we can reproduce it.

Comment: This is hard to understand. You have code that removes namespaces and then adds them again. You also have code that deals with preserving comments (and the XML declaration), although there are no comments in actors.xml. Please try to simplify your code and ask about one specific, reproducible problem at a time.

Comment: The requirement is to modify xml specific tag text via xpath without changing other xml tags or comments. (See the code #Find and update part, you'are right, the original requirement is quite simple). Without remoing namespace logic, the 'root. findall(xpath)' will throw an exception, you can have a try. And without the logic of the comments, when you write the xml back to file, the comments from the original file will be lost. We also need to add namespace back, otherwise, when you write the xml file, the namespace will be changed.